# unresolved external symbol while using trying to use dynamic library in solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I have one solution with two projects. One of the projects is dynamic library. Second is console app. I am trying to use function from dynamic library in the console app project.

I use `#include "..\header_from_library.h"` and I add reference into console app project. But when I tried to build console app project I get

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl start(void)" (?start@@YAXXZ) referenced in function main
```

The code in app project is

```
#include "../src/solver/solver_serial.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
    start(); // function in second project
}
```

Is there something next I have to set before I can call function from dynamic library project?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: In particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574400/11941443) of the duplicate.